# Sublime 3 forget default charset

Tags: character-encoding, sublimetext3

I have problem with default charset in Sublime 3 (`x64`, portable version). I converted all my .pwn and .inc files (PAWN language) to Central Europe (`Windows 1250`) charset and it works fine.

Problem is because Sublime forget my default charset and when I open again file(s), it sets charset to Western (`Windows 1252`). Is here any way to set default charset which Sublime won't forget?

I searched but I didn't found correct way(answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two settings you can use:

```js
"default_encoding": "UTF-8",
"fallback_encoding": "Western (Windows 1252)",
```

Those are the default values, just change them to `Central Europe (Windows 1250)` in your user preferences and you should be all set.

Comment: Nope, still nothing.


`{
 "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme",
 "font_size": 8,
 "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Vintage"
 ],
 "show_encoding": true,
 "default_encoding": "Central Europe (Windows 1250)", 
 "word_wrap": true
}
`

Comment: Don't change the `default_encoding`. Using UTF-8 is 99% of the time the correct call and the remaining 1% is when your files were saved in a different encoding, in which case loading the file will most likely fail and the fallback used instead. If you just set the fallback to your desired encoding, you should be fine and can still properly use UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks guys for help!